# Подскажите правильно ли делать такую запись

Tags: css, css3

Подскажите пожалуйста, является ли данная запись правильной, если нет, какие возможные альтернативы чтобы не задавать для двух классов одинаковые условия

```css
.soc p, .soc_text{
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
 color:#FFF;
 margin-bottom:30px;
 margin-right: 30px;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Запись наподобие

```
селектор1, селектор2 {}
```

Является правильно, называется это **группирование**.
Подробнее - [Группирование | htmlbook.ru](http://htmlbook.ru/samcss/gruppirovanie).

Даже больше, если группировать одинаковые стили для элементов, то можно оптимизировать CSS.
Задача - [Оптимизация CSS | htmlbook.ru](http://htmlbook.ru/practical/optimizaciya-css)

Comment: Спасибо большое